# Sort values in a pair

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I wonder how to sort values in a pair structure. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Minimal working example is pasted below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

pair <int, int> myPair;
myPair = make_pair(5, 3);
cout << myPair.first << " " << myPair.second << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: like [`std::minmax`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax/) instead of `std::make_pair` ?

Comment: @PiotrS. minmax works for fine for integers. What about strings?

Comment: @Andrej `minmax` by default uses *less-than* operator, which is applicable for `std::string` as well (hope you didn't mean `const char*`). `minmax` can be customized with arbitrary binary comparator as well, like `std::minmax(5, 3, std::greater<>{})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::pair<U,V>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) doesn't provide any ordering functionality by itself. If you don't want to write any additional code on your own (like conditional `std::swap`), then the closest you can get is to  use [`std::minmax`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax/) instead of `std::make_pair`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::pair<int, int> myPair = std::minmax(5, 3);
```

By default, `std::minmax` will use *less-than* operator (`<`) to determine the order of elements. It can be customized arbitrarily:

```
std::pair<int, int> a = std::minmax(5, 3, [](auto x, auto y){ return x*10 < y+20; });

std::pair<std::string, std::string> b = std::minmax("foo"s, "bar"s, std::greater<>{});
```